# Client-side web storage for offline fallbacks

Tags: offline

I'd be interested to know if anyone has experience working with ExpressionEngine feeding through data to a local client-side storage to run a microsite when it's offline.

Could it be possible to still use Channel entries and custom fields? a starting point could be through JSON data template or cached files.